# how to change a style of subclass using multi classes

Tags: css, less

I have a input field, I want to change the background using css/less because I cannot change my html code

I tried this

```css
/* bg_yellow */ .bg_yellow.o_form_field_many2one.o_with_button.o_form_field.o_form_required{ 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="o_form_field_many2one o_with_button bg_yellow o_form_field o_form_required">
  <div class="o_form_input_dropdown">
    <input class="o_form_input ui-autocomplete-input" id="o_field_input_2" autocomplete="off" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I fix the css class to change background of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and you're done...

```
input#o_field_input_2 {
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
```

Comment: ... since the input has an _unique_ **id**, why shouldn't we just use `#o_field_input_2{ background-color : yellowgreen; }` ?

Comment: `.bg_yellow.o_form_field>input,.bg_yellow.o_form_field>div>input{
        background: yellowgreen;
    }`